# SQL Syntax Error with ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running this query in SQL:

```
select
--CLAIM_ID,
--sum (paid_amount),
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by claim_id order BY claim_id) as asdf)
from [FRAUD].[dbo].[MU_GAPA_ADS_CLAIM_ANALYSIS_ALLACCOUNTS]
where (ALTGRP like '48000%') and (svcDAT between '10/01/2016' and '10/01/2016') 
Group By claim_id
```

However, I heep getting the following error:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Can someone please help me understand what is going on and how I can solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems you use way to many parentheses.

Comment: And be careful with those date strings. You should use the ANSI standard YYYYMMDD.

Comment: @HoneyBadger what would be the correct syntax, using the appropriate parentheses etc?

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't `row_number()`.  The problem is the parentheses around the column alias:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by claim_id order BY claim_id) as asdf
```

You should also fix the date constants:

```
select CLAIM_ID, sum(paid_amount),
       row_number() over (partition by claim_id order by claim_id) as asdf)
from [FRAUD].[dbo].[MU_GAPA_ADS_CLAIM_ANALYSIS_ALLACCOUNTS]
where ALTGRP like '48000%' and
     svcDAT between '2016-10-01' and '2016-10-01'
Group By claim_id;
```

All that said, the `row_number()` is always going to return "1" for this query, so you might as well leave it out.

Comment: Is this because I am grouping by Claim_ID only? I will add some other variables to group by which will result in Claim_ID repetitions. Essentially, I would like to get a count of the number of times each claim ID shows up

Comment: sounds like you just need COUNT(claim_id ) AS asdf

Comment: @Magretto . . . You should ask *another* question, with appropriate data and a description of what you want.  This seems to answer this question.